# Why isn't pandas join-on-join suffixes not being applied

Tags: python, pandas

If I join two identically indexed and columned dataframes, and then join another one, the third one does not get the suffix applied:

```
In [2]: alpha = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])                                                           

In [3]: beta = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])                                                            

In [4]: gamma = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])                                                           

In [5]: alpha                                                                                                                        
Out[5]: 
          A         B         C
0  0.611635  0.488644  0.970255
1  0.005383  0.745394  0.441660
2  0.610877  0.025026  0.022215

In [6]: alpha.join(beta, lsuffix='alpha', rsuffix='beta').join(gamma, rsuffix='gamma')                                               
Out[6]: 
     Aalpha    Balpha    Calpha     Abeta     Bbeta     Cbeta         A         B         C
0  0.611635  0.488644  0.970255  0.786817  0.083497  0.556911  0.994140  0.888822  0.615019
1  0.005383  0.745394  0.441660  0.089104  0.691462  0.310700  0.874293  0.694679  0.420962
2  0.610877  0.025026  0.022215  0.365142  0.289855  0.345496  0.492745  0.651312  0.355848

In [7]: gamma.join(alpha.join(beta, lsuffix='alpha', rsuffix='beta'), lsuffix='gamma')                                               
Out[7]: 
          A         B         C    Aalpha    Balpha    Calpha     Abeta     Bbeta     Cbeta
0  0.994140  0.888822  0.615019  0.611635  0.488644  0.970255  0.786817  0.083497  0.556911
1  0.874293  0.694679  0.420962  0.005383  0.745394  0.441660  0.089104  0.691462  0.310700
2  0.492745  0.651312  0.355848  0.610877  0.025026  0.022215  0.365142  0.289855  0.345496
```

The A, B and C columns should be Agamma, Bgamma and Cgamma, but no matter whether they are the left or the right of the join, the column labels don't get applied.

On a hunch I tried adding `.copy()` to the dataframes in the join commands.  No variation seemed to help:

```
In [8]: gamma.copy().join(alpha.copy().join(beta.copy(), lsuffix='alpha', rsuffix='beta'), lsuffix='gamma')                          
Out[8]: 
          A         B         C    Aalpha    Balpha    Calpha     Abeta     Bbeta     Cbeta
0  0.994140  0.888822  0.615019  0.611635  0.488644  0.970255  0.786817  0.083497  0.556911
1  0.874293  0.694679  0.420962  0.005383  0.745394  0.441660  0.089104  0.691462  0.310700
2  0.492745  0.651312  0.355848  0.610877  0.025026  0.022215  0.365142  0.289855  0.345496
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I am doing something wrong.  The `lsuffix` and `rsuffix` are only for overlapping columns, as it says in the doco.